# Embedded C++ DLL in VB.NET

Tags: c++, .net, dll, frameworks

I didn't find answer to this from msdn or from google so I decided to ask it here.

Is it possible to write a DLL in C++, then use it embedded in vb.net? From resource file, etc? I want the DLL to stay inside the .net -application.

This way I could use C++ code directly from vb.net app, without having it in HDD.

Possible or not?

Comment: Please use the comment section for discussion

Comment: Embedding DLLs in an executable and actually running the code in the DLL is not possible.  This is otherwise a problem that's solved every day, you embed DLLs into an executable called setup.exe, surely you've used one before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a **[C++ static library](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235627.aspx&sa=U&ei=Z2ArUsvqM8-2hAf69YDQBw&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNHVMV4NiRIjGXl8KTFnbXgkt6s4UA)**, and then reference it in a **[C++/CLI dynamic library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Consuming-C-Library-in-937458e5)** project.
The static library will be "embedded" into the C++/CLI .Net library.